# Insert Mysql de campos de varias tablas

Tags: mysql

Necesito ayuda para realizar un `INSERT` (o los que fueran necesarios).

Las tablas que tengo son:

- Tabla1: Id, Type, Año.
- Tabla2: Id, Type.
- Tabla3: Id, Año.

Necesito insertar en la **Tabla4**, el `Id` de la **Tabla2**, EL `Id` de la **Tabla3**, ademas añadir por cada año el TOTAL de Typo que hay.

Por ejemplo:

- 2012 rojo 200
- 2012 verde 56
- 2013 rojo 23
- 2014 verde 22

(pero en vez de rojo y 2012 seria su `Id` y el `total`)

Comment: Lo quieres hacer todo en un mismo Query? o se puede segmentar como sea necesario?

Comment: Me vale de las dos maneras.

Comment: ¿Podrías pasarnos las tablas con unos datos de ejemplo y el resultado esperado?